# RailsAdmin enum display existing value of the record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums, devise, roles, rails-admin

I have defined a User model in which there is a classical role

```
class User
enum role:[:user, :poweruser, :admin, :superadmin]
```

I am now using RailsAdmin to manage the fields of the user in **rails_admin.rb** file.
At the beginning, I manage the role attribute directly like that :

```
edit do
field :email do
  required true
end
field :password 
field :password_confirmation 
field :role 
...
```

Everything was fine. The current value is displayed (here **poweruser**), I get a combo automatically from RailsAdmin, with the 4 listed value. Perfect !

[image]

Now, I want to manage dynamically the list of roles : I need to restrict the list of roles regarding the current_user logged.
Therefore I use the **:enum** feature of RailsAdmin like that :

```
field :role, :enum do
          required true
          enum do
            if bindings[:view]._current_user.superadmin?
              {user:0, poweruser:1,admin:2,superadmin:3}
            elsif  bindings[:view]._current_user.admin?
              {user:0, poweruser:1,admin:2}
            else
              {user:0}
            end
          end
      end
```

This is working, the list is correctly restricted according to the current user role logged.

[image]

However, I would like that the initial value of the role should be set correctly, this value is not displayed at all : instead of the initial value **poweruser**, the '**Search**' word (*Chercher* in french) is displayed.
How could I solve this issue ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guillermo, but it does not answer to my problem.
The problem is that railsadmin is not able to select the enum field on edit. It does not concern the default value for new record.

Now, I have found that it is an open issue of railsadmin gem, and find this link :
[Not selecting enum field on edit #2669](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/2669) and got a workaround from [Richard Venneman](https://github.com/richardvenneman)

I have to change code in **file app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_enumeration.html.haml** and override the existing code by :

```
= form.select field.method_name, field.enum, { include_blank: true }.reverse_merge({ selected: form.object.class.send(field.method_name.to_s.pluralize)[field.form_value] }), field.html_attributes.reverse_merge({ data: { enumeration: true }, placeholder: t('admin.misc.search') })
```

It is working fine now ! So this problem is closed for me, until an official version of railsadmin !

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the block default_value

```
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      field :role do
        default_value do
          :poweruser
        end
      end
    end
  end
```